# what is the max limit of entities in a custom NER model

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy, bert-language-model, flair

what is the **maximum limit** of entities we can have in a spacy or bert based custom NER models ? I have seen examples over the web which have been trained to a max of 10 custom entities per model and even the Ontonotes data set has 18 entities, so does having certain number of entities in a NER model can impact the model learning abilities and performance ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a certain limit but increasing of number of classes would definitely effect the learning in a negative way. You can train a model with a 50 classes but the learning performance is depends on how your your dataset represent each class (is there a class imbalance problem etc. ) and whether your classes are distinguishable from each other easily or not.

Comment: For the record, there is no hard limit in spaCy. I would be surprised if other libraries had a hard limit either.